# I can't run the Android SDK Manager through the Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

This is the errors getting:

```
[2013-04-18 12:30:30 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2013-04-18 12:30:30 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
```

What should I do ?

Comment: move your sdk to a different folder and give it a try

Comment: Set `JAVA_HOME` environmental variable or add Android SDK to `Path`.

Comment: Make sure you are give the right sdk path into the preferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may 2 kinds of problem..
first is...
The adb tool has moved to platform-tools/

If you don't see this directory in your SDK, launch the SDK and AVD Manager (execute the android tool) and install "Android SDK Platform-tools"

Please also update your PATH environment variable to include the platform-tools/ directory, so you can execute adb from any location.

So you should also add C:/android-sdk/platform-tools to you environment path. Also after you modify the PATH variable make sure that you start a new CommandPrompt window

and 2nd is:

Other possibility is change directory (using cd) to the tools folder, and execute the command from there. Since the current directory (whatever it is) is usually in the PATH, the system will find it. But this is not handy, because you frequently want to execute this command being in a different directory.
just go through it and enjoy..

Answer (score 0):

Put the Android SDK at another place than the `%PROGRAMFILES%` folder. The Android SDK will modify itself by downloading new components, which is generally not allowed in your program files folder (except if you run with admin rights, which you shouldn't).

Put the SDK into an otherwise unused, writable location like C:\AndroidSDK. Avoid using blanks in folder names.